# Interface in Room and Retrofit

Tags: android, retrofit2, android-room

When using the **retrofit** library, you create an *interface* that contains functions with all your endpoints but you never implement it anywhere. My question is where is this interface implemented? I have noticed the same pattern when creating a **DAO** when using android **Room**

Comment: https://proandroiddev.com/how-does-retrofit-work-6ecad1bb683b
https://blog.mindorks.com/how-does-room-work-internally

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They use two different approaches, Retrofit takes advantage of Java reflection [proxy](https://www.baeldung.com/java-dynamic-proxies) which is a tool to implement interfaces in runtime, your proxy's `invoke` method will retrieve the called method scheme through reflection and can work based on that. In fact retrofit can work with method metadata only.

Proxy is a way to create objects from interfaces without implementing them using code, but by  a single invoke method which simply gets these arguments

```
@Override
    public Object invoke(Object proxy, Method method, Object[] args) 
      throws Throwable {
        Log.d("proxyCall", method.getName());

        return Response (...);
    }
```

You can get other info from method as well (like it's annotations e.g. @GET etc.)

On the other hand, Room uses [annotation processors](https://www.raywenderlich.com/8574679-annotation-processing-supercharge-your-development) to generate code during compile time (you add it's processor a.k.a. compiler in the gradle configuration using `annotationProcessor` or `kapt`).
You can find the Room's generated source codes inside the `build` folder of your module.

Comment: This is a nice breakdown. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Room Database uses the Annotation Processor and Reflection simultaneously. It uses Annotation Processor to generate Java Code for classes annotated as `@DAO` and `@Database` and generates implementation class with `_Impl` suffix.

It uses reflection to find the Database implementation class. When you call `Room.databaseBuilder(context, AppDatabase.class, databaseName).build();`It will call like this with the value of suffix being `_Impl`

```java
  @NonNull
    static <T, C> T getGeneratedImplementation(Class<C> klass, String suffix) {
        final String fullPackage = klass.getPackage().getName();
        String name = klass.getCanonicalName();
        final String postPackageName = fullPackage.isEmpty()
                ? name
                : (name.substring(fullPackage.length() + 1));
        final String implName = postPackageName.replace('.', '_') + suffix;
        //noinspection TryWithIdenticalCatches
        try {

            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            final Class<T> aClass = (Class<T>) Class.forName(
                    fullPackage.isEmpty() ? implName : fullPackage + "." + implName);
            return aClass.newInstance();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("cannot find implementation for "
                    + klass.getCanonicalName() + ". " + implName + " does not exist");
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Cannot access the constructor"
                    + klass.getCanonicalName());
        } catch (InstantiationException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Failed to create an instance of "
                    + klass.getCanonicalName());
        }
    }
```

Room has limited the use of reflection so the speed of the room is not affected much by reflection

Answer (score 1):

Retrofit is used the Java Dynamic Proxy approach to create classes at runtime, and this requires an interface so you just need to define your Interface and retrofit will build a type-safe implementation of your interface at runtime.